# Count number of null values for every column on a table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to calculate, for each column in a table, the percent of rows that are null.
For one column, I was using:

```
SELECT ((SELECT COUNT(Col1)
FROM Table1)
/        
(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1)) AS Table1Stats
```

Works great and is fast.
However, I want to do this for all ~50 columns of the table, and my environment does not allow me to use dynamic SQL.

Any recommendations? I am using snowflake to connect to AWS, but as an end user I am using the snowflake browser interface.

Comment: Please specify which database you are using

Comment: You can generate the query dynamically as a one off, and then just use that statically. Why can't you do `select count(Col1) / count(*) from Table1` and avoid the second lookup?

Answer (score 1):

You can combine this as:

```
SELECT COUNT(Col1) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)
FROM Table1;
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
SELECT AVG( (Col1 IS NOT NULL)::INT )
FROM Table1;
```

Comment: This works fine, and I can repeat for all 50 cols... but I was hoping there was a way to go about this other than copy and pasting 50 Field names.

Comment: You can use a spreadsheet to generate the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mix of `object_construct()` and `flatten()` to move the column names into rows. Then do the math for the values missing:

```sql
create or replace temp table many_cols as
select 1 a, 2 b, 3 c, 4 d
union all select 1, null, 3, 4
union all select 8, 8, null, null
union all select 8, 8, 7, null
union all select null, null, null, null;

select key column_name
  , 1-count(*)/(select count(*) from many_cols) ratio_null
from (
    select object_construct(a.*) x
    from many_cols a
), lateral flatten(x)
group by key
;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a SQL generator if you don't mind copying the text and running it once it's done.

```
-- SQL generator option:
select 'select' || listagg(' ((select count(' || COLUMN_NAME || ') from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF10000"."ORDERS") / ' || 
       '(select count(*) from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF10000"."ORDERS")) as ' || COLUMN_NAME, ',') as SQL_STATEMENT
from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" 
where TABLE_CATALOG = 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TPCH_SF10000' and TABLE_NAME = 'ORDERS'
;
```

If the copy and paste is not plausible because you need to script it, you can use the results of the SQL generator in a stored procedure I wrote to execute a single line of dynamic SQL:

```
call run_dynamic_sql(

select 'select' || listagg(' ((select count(' || COLUMN_NAME || ') from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF10000"."ORDERS") / ' || 
       '(select count(*) from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF10000"."ORDERS")) as ' || COLUMN_NAME, ',') as SQL_STATEMENT
from "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS" 
where TABLE_CATALOG = 'SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'TPCH_SF10000' and TABLE_NAME = 'ORDERS'

);
```

If you want the stored procedure, until it's published on Snowflake's blog it's available here: https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2021/01/22/running-dynamic-sql-in-snowflake/